# Convergence of $\sum \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\frac{1}{4^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Does the series
$$\sum \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\frac{1}{4^n}$$

converges?

**My attempt:** Since the ratio test is inconclusive, my idea is to use the Stirling Approximation for n!

$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!4^n} \sim (\frac{1}{4^n} \frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}(\frac{2n}{e})^{2n}}{\sqrt{2 n \pi} \sqrt{2n \pi} (\frac{n}{e})^{2n}} =\frac{(2)^{2n}}{4^n \sqrt{n \pi}}$$
The series of the secomd term diverges. It is correct to conclude thatthe series diverges?

Another ideas are welcome!

Thanks

Comment: What you got from Stirling doesn't look right.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Cannyou find the mistake?

Comment: Oh, I did. Thanks

Comment: Your approximate value for $4^{-n}{2n\choose n}$ (which presumably is meant to simplify to $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$) is still incorrect - I suggest you write out your use of Stirling and all the algebra in full.

Comment: As an aside, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{2n\choose n}x^n=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}$. See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for more information.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki can you please check my edit?

Comment: @Giiovanna That looks much better!

Comment: (Also, +1 for showing your work - as you've shown, the question is fairly straightforward once you have the right estimate, but it's still great to see _your_ efforts written out!)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Another approach:** Note that $\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}$ equals the binomial coefficient $\binom{2n}{n}$. The binomial coefficients $\binom{2n}{0}$, $\binom{2n}{1}$, ..., $\binom{2n}{2n}$ have sum $2^{2n} = 4^n$, thus their average is $\frac{4^n}{2n+1}$. Since $\binom{2n}{n}$ is the largest of these binomial coefficients, it is surely "above average": this means that $\binom{2n}{n} \geq \frac{4^n}{2n+1}$ from which it follows that
$$\frac{(2n)!}{n!n!} \frac{1}{4^n} = \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{4^n} \geq \frac{1}{2n+1}.$$ Since the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{1}{2n+1}$ diverges, the same holds for the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{4^n}$.

Comment: Nice idea! My approach leads to divergence to, but your is simplerand I am sure it is correct!

Comment: Of course, it's intuitively obvious that the central binomial coefficient(s) is/are largest, but not trivial; you should make sure that you either have that available or proven if you use this approach.

Comment: @user133281 Nice route!

Answer (score 6):

A much simpler way:
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{4(n+1)(n+1)}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\ge
\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}},
$$
since
$$
\left(\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}\right)^2=\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+2}\right)^2\ge 1-\frac{2}{2n+2}
=\frac{n}{n+1},
$$
and hence
$$
a_n=a_1\prod_{k=2}^n\frac{a_{k}}{a_{k-1}}\ge a_1\prod_{k=2}^n\sqrt{\frac{k-1}{k}}
=\frac{a_1}{\sqrt{n}},
$$
and hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\infty.
$$

Note that
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{4(n+1)(n+1)}=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2}=1-\frac{1}{2n+2}=1-\frac{1}{2n}+{\mathcal O}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).
$$
This series diverges due to [Gauss Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html) otherwise known as [Raabe's Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

Comment: Yiorgos S. Smyrlis: elegant proof!

Answer (score 3):

There is an identity: $$\sum_{k=0}^n {{2k}\choose k} {{2n-2k}\choose{n-k}} = 4^n$$

From this, we can calculate, for all $x$ with $|x|<1/4$:

$$\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty {{2n}\choose n} x^n\right)^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{k=0}^n {{2k}\choose k} {{2n-2k}\choose{n-k}}\right)x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 4^n x^n = \frac{1}{1-4x}$$

We conclude:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {{2n}\choose n} 4^{-n} = \lim_{x\to 1/4} \sum_{n=0}^\infty {{2n}\choose n} x^n = \lim_{x\to 1/4^-} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}} = \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

As you noted, Stirling gives an estimate $4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n} \ge \frac{c}{\sqrt n}$, which shows divergence; as others have said, it's enough to show $4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n} \ge \frac cn$, which is much easier than the Stirling estimate.  Here are three more arguments for $\frac cn$.

1. The most elementary one that I know (except perhaps the answer by user133281):
   $$
   4^n
   = \left(\sum_{k=0}^n 1\cdot\binom nk\right)^2
   \le \left(\sum_{k=0}^n 1^2\right) \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk^2\right)
   = (n+1)\binom{2n}{n}
   $$
   That's Cauchy-Schwarz and the identity proved in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583).
2. Using the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) representation of binomial coefficients:
   $$ \frac1{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}
   = \int_0^1 t^n (1-t)^n \,dt
   \le \frac1{4^n} $$
   since $\sqrt{t(1-t)}\le\frac12$ by AM/GM.
3. Using the [Wallis integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) representation of central binomial coefficients, that is,
   $$ \binom{2n}{n} = \frac{4^n}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2n} t \,dt $$
   (You can prove this by induction; a slicker way is to recall that, for $n\in\mathbb Z$,
   $$\frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{int} \,dt = \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if $n=0$} \\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
   Consequently, if $f(x) = \sum_{k=m}^n a_k x^k$ is a Laurent polynomial then $\frac1{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it}) \,dt = a_0$.  Now take $f(x)=(x+x^{-1})^{2n}$.)  Perhaps the simplest way to estimate the Wallis integral is
   $$ \int_0^{2\pi} \cos^{2n} t \,dt
   = 4\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n} t \,dt
   \ge 4\int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n} t \sin t \,dt
   = \frac4{2n+1}
   $$

Answer (score 1):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/932509) it is shown that
$$
\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi(n+\frac13)}}\le\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi(n+\frac14)}}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(2n)!}{n!\,n!}\frac1{4^n}
&\ge\frac1{\sqrt{\pi(n+\frac13)}}\\
&\ge\frac1{\pi(n+1)}\\
\end{align}
$$
compare with the Harmonic Series.