# equality with respect to Stirling's formula

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

Can we prove the equality:
$$
\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}\left(\, 1 \over 4\,\right)^{n}\,
{\left(\, 2n\,\right)! \over \left(\, n!\,\right)^{2}} = 1
$$
or the equality doesn't hold actually ?.

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty{2n\choose n}x^n=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x}}.~$ See [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: Can you answer useing Gauss's Test: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convergence of $\sum \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\frac{1}{4^n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951171/convergence-of-sum-frac2nnn-frac14n)

Comment: @StevenTaschuk That question is about convergence of the series; this one is about the value of its sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Stirling's formula, the terms in the sum are asymptotically
$$
\frac{1}{4^n}
 \frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}
      {\left(\sqrt{2\pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\right)^2} = 
\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}}{2 \pi n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}
$$
(if my algebra is correct), which gives you a divergent series.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of the first three terms is
$$\frac12+\frac38+\frac{5}{16}=\frac{19}{16}\ ,$$
and all terms are positive.  So the sum either converges to a value greater than $1$, or diverges.

Comment: According to CAS it diverges !!!.

Comment: Not surprised, but of course this is not needed in order to answer the OP's question.  Lukas Geyer also showed that the series diverges, but had to use Stirling's approximation which is very hi-tech compared with my method ;-)