# How to prove a formula using Vandermode's Convolution Formula

Tags: combinatorics

Need to prove this formula [image]

based on Vandermode's Convolution Formula which is
[image]

not sure how to  prove first one based on second one.

It could make sense if C(n, i) = C(n, r-i)
though, I am not sure if such identity exists. 
If it exists than second formula is pretty much first formula with just n and m being same value. If there is such an identity - please tell me how its name :)
I will be thankful for your explanation.

Comment: What happens in the second equation when $n = m = r$?

Comment: Also, $\displaystyle{n\choose k}={n\choose n-k}$

Comment: +1 for the username. But it's V*a*ndermonde.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combinatorial proof of summation of $\sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}^2= {2n \choose n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583/combinatorial-proof-of-summation-of-sum-k-0n-n-choose-k2-2n-choose)