# What is the probability that 2 subsets have same number of elements?

Tags: probability

Let X be a set containing n elements. If two subsets A & B of X are picked at random, what is the probability that A & B have the same number of elements?

My answer is $\frac{\binom{n}{0}^2+\binom{n}{1}^2+\binom{n}{2}^2+...+\binom{n}{n}^2}{2^n.2^n}$ but I cannot simplify it. Answer is given $\frac{1.3.5...(2n-1)}{2^n.n!}$
Please help me in this problem.

Comment: Can the same subset be picked twice?

Comment: yes same subset can be picked twice.

Comment: Actually it must be proved that:$$\binom{n}{0}^{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}^{2}=\binom{2n}{n}$$ Have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/148583/75923)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\sum_k{n \choose k}^2 = {2n \choose n} = {(2n)! \over (n!)^2}.$$