# Prove that the binomial coefficent $\binom{2p}{p} $ is $\equiv 2\pmod{p}$ using group actions.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, group-actions

I have to prove that the binomial coefficent $\binom{2p}{p} $ is $\equiv 2\pmod{p}$ using group actions.

I've tried with an action of $ C_p \times C_p$ upon the set of all numbers between $1$ and $2p$ but I'm blocked here.

P.s. here $C_p$ is the cyclic group of order p

Comment: Reproduce the proof of [Lucas' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem#Combinatorial_argument) for the simpler case of $m = 2p, n = p$. So it will follow that ${2p \choose p} = {2 \choose 1} \mod p$.

Answer (score 2):

We may consider every subset $S$ of $\{1,\ldots,2p\}$ with $p$ elements as a couple $\left(S\cap \{1,p\},S\cap\{p+1,2p\}\right)$, then consider the action (by shifting) of $C_p\times C_p$ on such couples. 
Iff both $S\cap\{1,p\}$ and $S\cap\{p+1,2p\}$ are non-empty, the equivalence class of a couple has exactly $p^2$ elements, hence we get:
$$ p^2 \mid \binom{2p}{p}-2 $$
that is:
$$ \binom{2p}{p}\equiv 2\!\!\pmod{p^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you, so I have some questions: 
1) The fact that I look at S as a couple of that type is only to see if S which between 1,p,p+1 and 2p is contained in S?
2)What is equivalence class in this case means? The orbit of an element? 
3)Why that "iff" holds?

Comment: @HaroldF: 1) Exactly, we split a subset into its "left part" an "right part" 2) $C_p$ acts on the left part by sending an element into its consecutive element, but $p$ into $1$; the same happens when $C_p$ acts on the right part: the action of $C_p$ maps $p+1$ into $p+2$ and so on, till $2p$ that is mapped to $p+1$. So we have that every subset, having non-empty left part and non-empty right part, can be mapped into $p^2$ different subsets by the action of $C_p\times C_p$. That gives an equivalence relation on the set of subsets having non-empty left and right parts,

Comment: in which every equivalence class has $p^2$ elements. It follows that $\binom{2p}{p}-2\equiv 2\!\!\pmod{p^2}$ as stated.

Comment: Thank you, now i see the point!

Answer (score 1):

Answer that lacks the application of group actions (so it might be useless for you).

For a proof of: $$\binom{2p}{p}=\sum_{k=0}^p\binom{p}{k}^2=2+\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{k}^2$$

have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/148583/75923).

Evidendly prime $p$ divides $\binom{p}{k}$ for each $k\in\{1,\dots,p-1\}$.

I don't know, but maybe some action can be found on a set of cardinality $\binom{2p}{p}$ that is split up in orbits of sizes $\binom{p}{k}^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Consider the rotations of a regular polygon with $2p$ vertices, $p$ of which are to be colored black and the others white.  Of the $2p\choose p$ colorings, there are $2$ that alternate black and white.  Can you show that the rest come in groups of $p$?

Comment: Thank you, like this point of view, but I cannot see the point, can you be more specific?

Comment: @HaroldF If the $\binom{2p}{p}$ colorings are $2$ plus a bunch of groups of $p$, then what is $\binom{2p}{p}$ mod $p$? There is no point in considering $C_p\times C_p$ here, $C_p$ is much more natural. This is also the point of Weaam's comment  above, the linked wikipedia section which you should read.

Comment: Yes, my question to the Point of Barry is that I cannot see why other colourings come in groups of p

Comment: @HaroldF The orbits all have size dividing $C_p$, so either $1$ or $p$. There are two fixed points (two rotation-invariant colorings), so the rest come in sets of $p$ (namely, in orbits of size $p$).