# Prove that $(^nC_0)^2 + (^nC_1)^2 + (^nC_2)^2 + \cdots + (^nC_n)^2 = {^{2n}C}_n$

Tags: permutations, combinations

Can anyone help me prove that in the most simple way possible?

Comment: Not sure how many duplicates exist for this question. Here is one: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/148583/321264.