# Binomial theorem coefficient question

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Use the binomial theorem to find the coefficient for $x^3$ on both sides of the expansion of:

$(1+x)^3$$(1+x)^3$ $=$ $(1+x)^6$

i. Hence show $(_3C_0)^2+(_3C_1)^2+(_3C_2)^2+(_3C_3)^2$ $=$ $_6C_3$

ii. Use the same argument with $(1+x)^n(1+x)^n = (1+x)^{2n}$ to prove

$\sum_{k=0}^n(_nC_k)^2=_{2n}C_n$

Thank you.

Comment: And what happened when you followed the directions?

Comment: What did you get for the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1+x)^6$? And what did you get for the coefficient of $x^3$ in $(1+x)^3(1+x)^3$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combinatorial proof of summation of $\sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}^2= {2n \choose n}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583/combinatorial-proof-of-summation-of-sum-k-0n-n-choose-k2-2n-choose) (Well, it's not exact duplicate, but the top voted answer there is what you are asking about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^k$ in a series. We also use the *[notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#History_and_notation)* $\binom{n}{k}$ instead of $_nC_k$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^3](1+x)^3(1+x)^3&=[x^3]\left(\sum_{j=0}^3\binom{3}{j}x^j\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^3\binom{3}{k}x^k\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^3\binom{3}{j}[x^{3-j}]\sum_{k=0}^3\binom{3}{k}x^k\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^3\binom{3}{j}\binom{3}{3-j}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^3\binom{3}{j}^2\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> on the other hand we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^3](1+x)^3(1+x)^3&=[x^3](1+x)^6\\
> &=[x^3]\sum_{j=0}^6\binom{6}{j}x^j\tag{5}\\
> &=\binom{6}{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *[binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)* twice.
- In (2) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule
  \begin{align*}
  [x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)
  \end{align*}
  to the summands of the left series.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^{3-j}$ from the right series.
- In (4) we use the *symmetry* $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$.
- In (5) we again apply the binomial theorem and select the coefficient of $x^3$.

> We conclude
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^3\binom{3}{j}^2=\binom{6}{3}\\
> \end{align*}

The calculation to show
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}^2=\binom{2n}{n}\\
\end{align*}
can be done analogously.