# How to show $ {n \choose m}{m \choose k}={n \choose k}{n-k \choose m-k}$ by counting pairs of sets $(A,B)$ in two ways

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How to show $ {n \choose m}{m \choose k}={n \choose k}{n-k \choose m-k}$ by counting pairs of sets $(A,B)$ in two ways and to deduce $\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}{n-k \choose m-k}=2^m{n \choose m} $

I am looking for a combinatorial proof. 
What is a combinatorical proof:
[Combinatorial proof of summation of $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}^2= {2n \choose n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583/combinatorial-proof-of-summation-of-sum-limits-k-0n-n-choose-k2-2n/2345307#2345307)

So basicaly i would like to explain the sum by dissolving it into dijunctive objects with meaning.

Comment: What is your work on the subject ?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively ... using only algebra
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n}{m} \binom{m}{k} =\frac{n!}{(n-m)!\color{red}{m!}}  \frac{\color{red}{m!}}{k!(m-k)!} =\frac{n!}{k!\color{blue}{(n-k)!}}  \frac{\color{blue}{(n-k)!}}{(n-m)!(m-k)!}= \binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k}
\end{eqnarray*}
...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k} = \sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{n}{m} \binom{m}{k} =\binom{n}{m} \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} =\binom{n}{m} 2^m.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 5):

Question: in how many ways can we form an $m$-person committee with a $k$-person subcommittee from a group of $n$ people?

Answer 1: First choose the committee in $\binom{n}{m}$ ways. Then choose the subcommittee from the committee in $\binom{m}{k}$ ways. So there are $\binom{n}{m}\binom{m}{k}$ possible such possibilities.

Answer 2: First choose the $k$ subcommittee members in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways. Then fill in the remaining $(m-k)$ committee members from the remaining pool of $(n-k)$ people. So there are $\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k}$ ways to do this.

Both quantities answer the same question (which only has one answer) so they must be equal. That is,
$$\binom{n}{m}\binom{m}{k} = \binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k}$$

---

For the second part, we use the same logic except allow the subcommittee to be any size, between $0$ and $m$ (the size of the committee). I believe you have a typo - you'll want the summation to go up to $m$, not $n$.

Then the right hand side represents first choosing the $m$ committee members, and from there picking a random subset of them to form the subcommittee. There are $2^{m}$ subsets of a set of $m$ people, so $2^{m}\binom{n}{m}$ gives the total number of possibilities.

Alternatively, you can first pick the subcommittee in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways and fill in the remaining committee members in $\binom{n-k}{m-k}$. But since $k$ is not fixed (the subcommittee can be of any size), we have to sum this over $k$ from $0$ to $m$, which gives the left hand side.