# How do I prove this combination equation using induction?

Tags: combinatorics, induction, combinations

[image: Image-1]

[image: Image-2]

The proof I tried is in the aforementioned images, but I don't know how to proceed after a point. I would like a completed version of that proof or if it isn't viable, I would also love exploring other proofs along with a reason why my proof isn't a viable one.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: please write it out instead of having pictures

Comment: It is a rather well known result. Certainly already addressed in this site. Are you obliged to prove it by induction?

Comment: Hi! I'm a mobile user and would have used MathJax if I posted this question using a PC, because it is very inconvenient to type using mobile, sorry if I broke a rule

Comment: No, I'm not obliged to prove it by induction, however the first method I tried for this problem was the induction method, but I didn't know how to complete it. I just thought of this induction proof as a learning opportunity

Comment: A simpler proof than induction is provided here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583/combinatorial-proof-of-summation-of-sum-limits-k-0n-n-choose-k2-2n

Comment: Yeah I do know that proof, but I was just wondering if I could prove it by induction

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for asking a duplicate question. I wasn't aware of that notation for combinations before so I couldn't search it here like that