# Prove that $\binom{n}{0} ^2 + \binom{n}{1} ^2 + \binom{n}{2} ^2 + ... + \binom{n}{n} ^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$.

Tags: combinatorics

How can I prove the following statement?

$$\binom{n}{0} ^2 + \binom{n}{1} ^2 + \binom{n}{2} ^2 + ... + \binom{n}{n} ^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$$

I know that:

$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$$

But I don't see how I could use it to prove the given problem.

Comment: Is that the only relation you know among the binomial coefficients??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinatorial proof of summation of $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}^2= {2n \choose n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583/combinatorial-proof-of-summation-of-sum-limits-k-0n-n-choose-k2-2n) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7B0%7D%20%5E2%20%2B%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7B1%7D%20%5E2%20%2B%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7B2%7D%20%5E2%20%2B%20...%20%2B%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bn%7D%20%5E2%20%3D%20%5Cbinom%7B2n%7D%7Bn%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: More similar or identical questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/148583?lq=1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+x)^{2n} & = & (1+x)^{n}(1+x)^{n}\\
 & = & \left[\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}x^{i}\right]\left[\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}x^{j}\right]
\end{eqnarray*}
Expand the right hand side and observe that the $x^{n}$ term is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \binom{n}{0}x^{0}\cdot\binom{n}{n}x^{n}+\binom{n}{1}x^{1}\cdot\binom{n}{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+\binom{n}{n-1}x^{n-1}\cdot\binom{n}{1}x^{1}+\binom{n}{n}x^{n}\cdot\binom{n}{0}x^{0}\\
 & = & \left[\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{n-i}\right]x^{n}\\
 & = & \left[\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{i}\right]x^{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
The $x^{n}$ in the left hand side is just $\binom{2n}{n}x^{n}$.
Therefore $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}^{2}=\binom{2n}{n}$.