# DNA partition function

Tags: power-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I am looking to calculate the following sum:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N{N\choose k}^2x^k
$$
The sum appears, e.g., in the context of calculating the partition function of a DNA, where the nucleotides in the two parallel strands can form $k$ pairs with pairing probability $p$ and energy $E_k=-k\Delta$ (assuming that the bonds do not cross). Then the partition function (average over nucleotide configurations) is given by
$$
Z(\beta) = \sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{k=0}^N{N\choose k}^2p^ke^{\beta k \Delta}
$$

I know that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N{N\choose k}^2 = {2N\choose N},
$$
and it seems that there should be a simple way to get to the desired identity... on the other hand, the simplicity might be misleading.

Comment: Possible repeat of this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583/combinatorial-proof-of-summation-of-sum-limits-k-0n-n-choose-k2-2n

Comment: @klein4 here I am asking for a more general result.

Comment: Fun question +1. some more background would be nice. Although bio is not the main thing here , so this is rather a personal question I guess. maybe a link in the comment is better and easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}^2x^k=(1-x)^n \,P_n\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$$ where appear Legendre polynomials.

Comment: Could you please add some steps on how you derived this?