# Central binomial coefficient identity

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2n)!}{(k! (n-k)!)^2} = \binom{2n}{n}^2$$

The original combinatorial interpretation was something like how many strings of length $2n$ with 4 letters A,B,C,D have $k$ A's, $k$ B's, $n-k$ C's, and $n-k$ D's. From looking at the first few values, this looks like the square of the number of strings of length $2n$ with 2 letters, $n$ A's and $n$ B's.

Is there a nice combinatorial proof for this? I was thinking something like taking two strings with $n$ A's and $n$ B's, for example AAABBB and ABABAB, then mapping each pair of letters from both strings to one of four new letters. Then there are $k$ AA's, $n-k$ AB's, $k$ BB's, and $n-k$ BA's. Is this correct? Is there a nice algebraic proof too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your combinatorial argument seems fine. Here's an algebraic proof:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(2n)!}{(k! (n-k)!)^2}$$
$$= (2n)!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{(k! (n-k)!)^2}$$
$$= \frac{(2n)!}{n!n!}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(n!)^2}{(k! (n-k)!)^2}$$
$$ = \binom{2n}{n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2$$
It is a [well-known fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148583/combinatorial-proof-of-summation-of-sum-limits-k-0n-n-choose-k2-2n) that $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$. This yields the required expression.

Comment: This is a nice technique. I saw the sum term was almost (n choose k) but didn't see how to transform (2n)! into n!s.